# How can I clear value of textarea in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to delete content of some elements based on the drop down selection. I have tried this code the alert shows the new value is empty but when I save it, targeted element still has content.

Here's my code:

```
var res = document.getElementById("select-result").value;                                               //alert(res);
function clearValues(id, inputType) {
    var td = document.getElementById(id);

        if (td != undefined || td != null) {
            var res = td.getElementsByTagName(inputType)[0].value;                                                  
            alert(res); // returns the content of element
            if (res != "") {                                            
               res = "";                                                            
               alert("New res value: " + res); //returns empty
            } 
        }
}
```

Note: 
    If i manually remove content of the target element it saves it as empty. That's puzzling
    for me. What's the difference shouldn't javascript make things easier rather than      manually emptying fields.

Comment: show your saving part pls..

Comment: innerText or innerHtml ti reassign the value to ""

Comment: @Sudhir, its part of the application you just call it.

Comment: Not sure if it works for your purposes but you can always use the `reset()` method to reset your form. Of course this will return all form elements back to their original value.

Comment: in your `if` condition, always `res` is expect to be empty. so you don't need to check value of that element. Just do `res = ""` in your if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `res` to the value of the textbox - not to the `value` property. So you're only setting the `res` variable to empty, not the textbox's value. Try this, instead:

```js
var res = document.getElementById("select-result").value; 
function clearValues(id, inputType) {
    var td = document.getElementById(id);

        if (td != undefined || td != null) {
            var res = td.getElementsByTagName(inputType)[0].value;
            if (res != "") {             
               td.getElementsByTagName(inputType)[0].value = "";  
            } 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've assigned the value of the textarea to a new variable, `res`, but `res` is not a pointer to the value, it's basically a duplicate copy of that value and any changes made to `res` will not be reflected in the original value.

Consider this code:

```
var fruit1 = "apples"
var fruit2 = fruit1;

fruit2 = "oranges"

alert(fruit1); // still "apples"
alert(fruit2); // now "oranges"
```

So, you want to change the actual `value` property of the original elements like so:

```
td.getElementsByTagName(inputType)[0].value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function clearValues(id, inputType) {
    var td = document.getElementById(id);

    if (td != undefined || td != null) {
        var element = td.getElementsByTagName(inputType)[0];
            elmValue = element.value;                                                
        if (elmValue != '') {                                            
           element.value = "";                                                            
        } 
    }
}
```